# JSON encode array but keep one parameter as integer

Tags: php, arrays, json

Can I `json_encode` an array, but with keeping some specific numerical parameters numerical (integer)?

```
$arr= [
       'name'       => 'myName',
       'age'        => 30,
       'birthDate'  => '1992'
      ];
json_encode($arr); // output {"name":"myName", "age":"30", "birthdate":"1992"}
json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); // output {"name":"myName", "age":30, "birthdate":1992}
```

desired output: `{"name":"myName", "age":30, "birthdate":"1992"}`

Comment: Curiosity is getting the best of me. What would be the use case for this?

Comment: here https://onlinephp.io/c/7127a  your code already returns `{"name":"myName","age":30,"birthDate":"1992"}`

Comment: @War10ck APIs integration. Collecting the data from input fields into the array, and then passing them as json object, only some values must be passed as integers

Comment: @diegod in my environment, it doesn't, FYI my environment is laravel based

Comment: to me it looks very strange you are having that exact behaviour. Usually there are issues when trying to force string to int when holding numeric values (using the flag JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK and thus you've got "1992" converted to 1992 there). But unfortunately there are not enough information on this question to give further help. So far trying to replicate your scenario with php5.4 to php8 it always behaves correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this worked:

```
`$arr= [
   'name'       => 'myName',
   'age'        => (int)30,
   'birthDate'  => '1992'
  ];`
```

output :
`{"name":"myName", "age":30, "birthDate":"1992"}`